# Как реализовать вывод текста из button в input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

При нажатии на кнопку должен выводиться текст из нее в input. Ничего подобного не нашла, как это реализовать?

```
<div class="form-group people-block">
    <label class="form-people">People</label>
    <form><input readonly type="text" name="people" class="people-input" id="people"></form>

<div class="people-choice">
<div class="people-choice-item">
    <button class="choice-button" onclick="return false">1-2 People</button></div>
<div class="people-choice-item">
    <button class="choice-button" onclick="return false">3 People</button></div>
<div class="people-choice-item">
    <button class="choice-button" onclick="return false">4 People</button></div>
```

Comment: `onclick="return false"` — В этом нет никакого смысла, в данном случае. Можно убрать. return false прописывают, чтобы отключить поведение элемента "по умолчанию". Т.е. ссылка с `onclick="return false"` не будет открываться, чекбокс - не будет отмечаться и т.п.

Answer (score 1):

Без JQuery

```js
function foo() {
  let btn = document.querySelectorAll('.choice-button');
  let input = document.querySelector('.people-input');
  
  // Развешиваем событие клика на кнопки
  for(let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    btn[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      // При клике на кнопку записываем ее значение в инпут
      input.value = this.innerText;
    });
  }

}


foo();
```

```html
<div class="form-group people-block">
    <label class="form-people">People</label>
    <form><input readonly type="text" name="people" class="people-input" id="people"></form>
</div>
<div class="people-choice">
<div class="people-choice-item">
    <button class="choice-button" onclick="return false">1-2 People</button>
</div>
<div class="people-choice-item">
    <button class="choice-button" onclick="return false">3 People</button>
</div>
<div class="people-choice-item">
    <button class="choice-button" onclick="return false">4 People</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Прежде чем что-либо искать надо провести декомпозицию задачаи. Выделите составляющие:

- Добавить обработчик клика на все кнопки
- Получить текст нажатой кнопки
- Установить значение инпута

Решение каждой частной проблемы найти довольно просто.

```js
$(".choice-button").click(function(){
   $("#people").val( $(this).text() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>People</label>
<input readonly class="people-input" id="people"/>


<button class="choice-button">1-2 People</button>
<button class="choice-button">3 People</button>
<button class="choice-button">4 People</button>
```